# Android Image Processing detect color and put contour lines

Tags: android, image-processing

I am trying to make an android app that has the capability of Image processing. How do I put contour lines with pixels that have similar colors simply by using bitmap?

I have seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DRI1Kj4BhI) but it is live processing, displaying the contour lines. I wanted to use static image for my application and display contour lines with pixels that have similar color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should think about an image-processing library to do the work for you! I think [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) is a good choice. Then you load your image, convert it into HSV-space  and apply a color threshold with `inRange`. In the result image you detect your contours with `findContours` and draw them with `drawContours` or `polylines`. Done!

**Edit**

Convert your input image, e.g. RGB into hsv:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb,hsv,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
```

Define upper and lower values! Look at the HSV color wheel and pick the right range. Be aware that HSV has fit into 3 8 bit- channels, but the H channel does not, so you have to divide this value by 2. The range for H is 0-180 in OpenCV.
Here an example for red:

```
Scalar lower(0,100,100);
Scalar upper(10,255,255);
Core.inRange(hsv, lower, upper, segmentedImage);
```

[image]

Then use:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(segmentedImage, contours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Now you can iterate through each contour and do some stuff!

Comment: What is the purpose of inRange? Is that the acceptable range of looking similar color?

Comment: Yes indeed. You van specify your lower and upper bound. The values In this range will be segmented. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) for a detailed description

Comment: Do you have any snippet for detecting similar colors ?

Comment: I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: What is the diff. between findContours and drawContours? Because as I have seen in the camerablob example there is also drawContours.

Comment: `findContours` detects contours in a binary image and with `drawContours` you can vizualize(draw) your found contours into a color image!