# Android color splash

Tags: android, image-processing, pixel, photo

Can someone suggest me a fast method or a library for color splash effect? For example, I select a color and a photo gets desaturated for all colors except that one I have picked.

I have tried using pixel by pixel color check and then replace the color but it is too slow for big images.

```
int width = originalImage.getWidth();
int height = originalImage.getHeight();
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
originalImage.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

for (int x = 0; x < pixels.length; ++x) {
     pixels[x] = Distance(pixels[x], fromColor) < 4 ? targetColor : pixels[x];
}

Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, originalImage.getConfig());
newImage.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);


public int Distance(int a, int b) {
     return Math.abs(Color.red(a) - Color.red(b)) + Math.abs(Color.green(a) -
                     Color.green(b)) + Math.abs(Color.blue(a) - Color.blue(b));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here are the original and the processed images, the color I am keeping is #ff9350:
[image]
[image]

Comment: @AnderBiguri yup my mistke that's i asked for on expected output image in my previous comment

Comment: What language are you using that this is too slow?

Comment: You might have to split this part out to c++ and do the operations in neon. If everything done right, you can have theoretical speed up of 16x for 8bit ints and 4x for 32 bit ints.

Comment: I don't speak Android, so I can't see the code where you desaturate - can you add that please, or identify the lines that do it?

Comment: This code only checks if the color is similar to the one I have selected, and it alone is slow, with color changing is even slower.

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go over possible color `RGB` values and prepare`HashSet` containing only those color values that should not be
desaturated. It seems that there should not be a lot of values.

After that you will be able to check whether the color should be desaturated or not. Thus, you will get rather long precalculation for a new given color, but your code that converts photo will become faster.

It can be implemented like so (haven't tested it under `Android`, just some kind of `Java` pseudo-code to show the idea):

```
// precalculation
Set<Color> keptColors = new HashSet<Color>();
final int MAX_DISTANCE = 4;
for (int r=red(fromColor)-MAX_DISTANCE; r<=red(fromColor)+MAX_DISTANCE; r++) {
    for (int g=green(fromColor)-MAX_DISTANCE; g<=green(fromColor)+MAX_DISTANCE; g++) {
        for (int b=blue(fromColor)-MAX_DISTANCE; b<=blue(fromColor)+MAX_DISTANCE; b++) {
            if (Distance(rgb(r,g,b)), fromColor) < MAX_DISTANCE {
                keptColors.add(rgb(r,g,b));
            }
        }
    }
}
...

// in you photo processing code
keptColors.contains(pixels[x]) ? pixels[x] : targetColor;
```

Comment: How do I go over all possible color RGB?

Comment: I have added a possible implementation example

Comment: Why would the hash calculation be any faster than the distance calculation?

Comment: The `hashset` calculation is not faster, but when `hashset` is calculated then you don't need to calculate color distance on each pixel, you just lookup if its color is present in the `hashset` which is faster than color distance calculation. So you spend some time before starting photos processing, but then processing will be faster.

Comment: After some thinking I realized that with your distance calculation algorithm it is enough to pass over ±4 values around `fromColor` color component value, to get all values that pass the distance check. I improved the algorithm, however the checks that iterated color component value are inside theirs limits (0..255) are omitted, add them yourself please

Answer (score 0):

use `inRange` function in OpenCV to isolate a Color

```
Scalar lower(0,100,100);
Scalar upper(10,255,255);
Core.inRange(hsv, lower, upper, segmentedImage);
```

check out this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39525710/16930239)